# How to make gcc add a check after every floating point instruction?

Tags: gcc, riscv

Currently, RISC-V ISA does not require hardware to generate traps for floating point exception. Traps can be useful while debugging.

IEEE 754 defines five basic types of floating point exceptions:

Invalid operation

Division by zero

Overflow

Underflow

Inexact

I am interested in working on gcc for RISC-V so that it adds a check after every statement with floating point.

Check should be about whether any exception flag is set or not. If any flag is set, control should pass to exception handling routine.

Whenever any of these exception occurs, corresponding bit in floating point control and status register (fcsr) is set.

Comment: I think it should be done by the hardware not ISA. Implementation should raise the exception when it happens.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kinds of exceptions you're expecting to catch?

Comment: @FeelTheBurns i have made the edit.